# Error while Regex named capturing groups

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.0

For one of my application I'm trying to read test from `<textarea>` tag. Below mentioned pattern worked perfectly before, in Visual studio 2010. But in Visual studio 2013 it returns error "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: i"

My regex pattern `string exp = @"<textarea[^>]*id=['""]objCodePress_QB_Query['""].*?>(?<xtract>(.*?))</textarea>";`

and string sample that I'm looking is

```
<textarea id="objCodePress_QB_Query" name="objCodePress_QB_Query" style="width:100%;" rows=20 class="codepress sql">Hello this is a test</textarea>
```

Is there any update in regex for new version or how I fix this ?

Comment: Please post full relevant code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew code line http://prntscr.com/aocs0b

Comment: It means you did not obtain a match. You should check `mc.Count` if it is not `0` before subtracking `1` from it. I think all you need is `RegexOptions.Singleline`. Or add `(?s)` at the pattern start.

Comment: no I'm trying to collect value from 'xtract' named group in the pattern

Comment: Yes, you can use the named capture group. I just mean you can have newlines in the input, that is why you do not get matches.

Comment: Just note that [your regex works](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3ctextarea%5b%5e%3e%5d*id%3d%5b%27%22%5dobjCodePress_QB_Query%5b%27%22%5d.*%3f%3e(%3f%3cxtract%3e.*%3f)%3c%2ftextarea%3e&i=%3ctextarea+id%3d%22objCodePress_QB_Query%22+name%3d%22objCodePress_QB_Query%22+style%3d%22width%3a100%25%3b%22+rows%3d20+class%3d%22codepress+sql%22%3eHello+this+is+a+test%3c%2ftextarea%3e)

Comment: To make absolutely sure this doesn't bleed out, you should use `(?<xtract>[^<>]*?)`; any actual < or > inside a text area should be html-encoded anyway, as far as I know.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew finally it get fixed. Some special characters made the issue (in my case new line, as it's a text-area text) . I removed the line breaks and the patters worked perfectly. 

For details Please try to paste a string with line breaks

Comment: And did you try to follow my advice and use `string exp = @"(?s)<textarea[^>]*id=['""]objCodePress_QB_Query['""].*?>(?<xtract>(.*?))</textarea>";` with your original input?

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear that the issue you have is related to whitespace.

When you declare the Regex object, use `RegexOptions.Singleline` to force the `.` to match any characters including a newline.

Another solution is to add `(?s)` right at the beginning of your pattern.